# excel datepicker not visible after being hidden

Tags: excel, datepicker, vba

I have a userform with the datepicker (date and time picker control 6.0) being hidden when I press a button

```
DatePicker.Visible = False
```

then visible again with another button

```
DatePicker.Visible = True
```

However, I can only describe this as a bug or something. 
It is visible in that it is now present again on the userform, but not visible in that you cannot actually see it.

When you click on the location on the form where the datepicker is, then you reveal part of it. Say you managed to click on the year, it would highlight and you would be able to see the year. 
You then click on where the month would be an it reavels that as well.
Same again for day, and the drop down icon.

What is going on? Is there anyway to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your date picker inside a frame.  Then toggle the frame visibility on and off instead of the date picker.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Frame1.Visible = False
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Frame1.Visible = True
End Sub
```